# Manual weight updates: torch.autograd returns none, why?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision, pytorch-geometric

I am new to pytorch and it may sound a simple question, sorry for that. I have written a function that updates the parameters of a network manually:

```
def update_params(self, loss, update_lr):
        # parameter update
        updated_params = OrderedDict()
        for name, param in self.graph_model.gnn.named_parameters():
            if param.requires_grad:
                grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, param, create_graph=True,  allow_unused=True)
                if grad is None:
                    updated_params = param
                else:
                    pdb.set_trace()
                    updated_params = param - update_lr * grad
            updated_params[name] = updated_params
        return updated_params
```

the loss is as follows:

```
loss
tensor([0.0693], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

and the first param of loop is :

```
(Pdb) param
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.2142, -0.1182, -0.2988,  ...,  0.2933, -0.0804, -0.3286],
        [-0.1250,  0.2673,  0.1617,  ...,  0.2363,  0.2026, -0.2973],
        [ 0.0588,  0.2348, -0.2333,  ...,  0.1882,  0.0286, -0.3238],
        ...,
        [-0.1961,  0.1434,  0.0306,  ...,  0.3135,  0.2239, -0.0953],
        [ 0.1190,  0.2062, -0.2643,  ...,  0.3116,  0.1146, -0.1994],
        [ 0.0340, -0.2294,  0.2095,  ..., -0.2376,  0.0456,  0.3151]],
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

the grad is none for the first param (first iteration in the loop)

```
(pdb) grad
(None,)
```

however, when I check

```
(Pdb) grad is None
False
```

it returns False (means goes to the `else`). I am not sure where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: how do you call `update_params`; also `grad is None` is returning `False` because it's a tuple comprising a `None`. E.g., `not all(grad)` would return `True`.